# C# razor input var to controller search sql

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I am doing what should be a basic programming item but I seem to be missing something on how MVC works.  I have a web page that gets inventory items from a database and displays them.  I added a partial view that has a menu bar that I want to use on other views (at this point not robust).  In the menu bar I added a text box and search button.  I want to search the inventory database for the text entered in the text box.  I can't seem to get the InventoryController to allow me to add a select statement so I can return the data to the list view.  Maybe the partial view and view don't interact like I hoped they would.

Should I think of partial views added to a view as not sharing input data?
Can I do a select/find search using this format or should I use multiple controllers/views?

List.cshtml
    @model WebUI.Models.InventoryListViewModel1

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Items";
}

@Html.Partial("MenuView1")

<h2>test</h2>

    <div>
        <table class="productTable">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th class="item">Item</th>
                    <th class="descrip">Description</th>
                    <th class="color">Color</th>
                    <th class="height">Height</th>
                    <th class="width">Width</th>
                    <th class="depth">Depth</th>
                    <th class="manuf">Manufacturer</th>
                    <th class="manpartno">ManPartNo</th>
                    <th class="barcode">BarCodeNo</th>
                    <th class="qtyOnHnd">In Stock</th>
                    <th class="qtyOnOrdr">On Order</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            @foreach (var p in Model.Inventory)
            {
                <tr id="itemRow">
                    <td class="item">@p.item</td>
                    <td class="descrip">@p.description</td>
                    <td class="color">@p.color</td>
                    <td class="height">@p.height</td>
                    <td class="width">@p.width</td>
                    <td class="depth">@p.depth</td>
                    <td class="manuf">@p.manufacturer</td>
                    <td class="manpartno">@p.manPartNo</td>
                    <td class="barcode">@p.barCodeNo</td>
                    <td class="qtyOnHnd"></td>
                    <td class="qtyOnOrdr"></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>

 <div class="pager">

    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo1, x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}))

</div>
```

MenuView1.cshtml

```
@{
    var inventoryItem = "";
    if (IsPost)
{
    inventoryItem = Request["inventorysearch"];
}

<form method="post">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class="mainMenuBar"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="mainMenuBar"><a href="Inventory">Inventory</a></li>
            <li class="mainMenuBar"><a href="Clients">Clients</a></li>
            <li class="mainMenuBar">
                <input type="text" name="inventorySearch" /></li>
            <li class="mainMenuBar">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" /></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

}

InventoryListViewModel1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using DomainClasses.entities;

namespace WebUI.Models
{
    public class InventoryListViewModel1
    {
        public IQueryable<InventoryClass1> Inventory { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo1 PagingInfo1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

InventoryController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DomainClasses.Abstract;
using DomainClasses.entities;
using DomainClasses.concrete;
using WebUI.Models;

namespace WebUI.Controllers
{
   public class InventoryController : Controller
   {
        private IInventoryRepository1 repository;
        public int PageSize = 5;

        public InventoryController(IInventoryRepository1 inventoryRepository)
        {
            this.repository = inventoryRepository;
        }

    //
    // GET: /Invenotry/

        public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
        {
            InventoryListViewModel1 model = new InventoryListViewModel1
            {
                Inventory = repository.inventory
                .OrderBy(p => p.item)
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),
                 PagingInfo1 = new PagingInfo1
                {
                   CurrentPage = page,
                   ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                   TotalItems = repository.inventory.Count()
                }

            };

            return View(model);

        }

        public ViewResult MenuView1(string inventorysearch)
        {
            InventoryListViewModel1 model = new InventoryListViewModel1
            {
                Inventory = repository.inventory
                .Select (recieve and error that Select is a bad method)

            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to change your menu to use an ajax form, and return a partial view that you update the page with.  See this for an example: http://blog.falafel.com/ajaxbeginform-with-mvc-4/

Comment: I now have it passing data to the controller not using an ajax form but a HTML form. Thanks for the help.